# Using the XML Layout file instead of Java code for creating a TextView to display a message received through intent

Tags: java, android, xml, android-intent, android-fragments

I am learning how to develop apps for android.

I followed the tutorial by Google [Building Your First App](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html).

The idea is basically to write a message in a fragment, submit it with a button, the message is passed through the `intent` and displayed in the second fragment.

My question is about the part where we display the message. This is how it was done in the tutorial:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Get the message from the intent
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    // Create the text view
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText("You submitted: "+message);


    // Set the text view as the activity layout
    setContentView(textView);

}
```

I learned that the UI components can be implemented using XML, or Java, in this case obviously the tutorial uses Java to make a new TextView with the data received through the `intent`. I was trying to redo that part, but this time without relying that much on Java when it comes to the view. So I replaced the part under `// Create the text view` by:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display_message);
textView.setText(message);
```

And in the `fragment_display_message.xml` I had the following element:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/display_message"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />
```

It throws a `NullPointerException` at `textView.setText(message);`

I wonder why this happens, why can't it be done this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you should call

```
setContentView(R.layout.fragment_display_message);
```

before you call

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display_message);
textView.setText(message);
```

but it's a fragment?

Comment: This worked! and yes it is a fragment. Could you please explain to me why it works this way?

Comment: actually it makes sense now.. Because since we haven't created the TextView through the Java code, we can't setContentView to it.

Comment: AFAIK, when you called findViewById, it will search the current contentview you used for your app, and if you never set any view, it will return null. So never forget to call setContentView before findViewById :D

Comment: @MohamedKhamis After reading the [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html#CreateActivity), actually the `onCreate()` is inside `Activity`, not `Fragment`. That's why it's working. If it's `Fragment` instead, you have to inflate the layout inside `onCreateView()`. As for why this answer works, both of you are correct. In the tutorial, we create a `TextView` first, then we set the content layout. OTOH, you want to inflate (set) the layout first and then find the `TextView` :)

Comment: @AndrewT yes that's why I ask "but it's a fragment?" because i think it's weird to set fragment inside oncreate method.
you should call it from different class from your activity and extend fragment, inside the createview method using layout inflater. but as long as the class not extend Fragment, it's OK to call it inside onCreate method